# Error while installing vuze in Ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: ubuntu

I am getting problem during installation of VUZE.

It says :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vuze : Depends: libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install through `tar.gz` files but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Vuze through `snap` (preinstalled on Ubuntu 18.04):

```
snap find vuze
```

sample output:

```
Name     Version         Developer  Notes  Summary

vuze-vs  5.7.6.0-snap1     vs         -      Vuze is a powerful, open source, bittorrent client.
```

Install vuze:

```
$ sudo snap install vuze-vs
$ vuze-vs
```